# How to inject SharedViewModel using dagger?

Tags: android

I create my SharedViewModel in Activity :

```
 mOrdersViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory.get(OrdersViewModel.class);
```

After, I  subscribe to the LiveData in the other components(Fragments)

```
 mOrdersViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(OrdersViewModel.class);
```

But  I want to use  `mOrdersViewModel`  so `@Inject OrdersViewModel;`

How can I inject my mOrdersViewModel. Help me please (.

Answer (score 3):

At your **`Component`**, inject your activity like this :

```
void inject(Activity activity);
```

And in your **`Module`** provide dependency like this for your **`ViewModel`**:

```
public Module(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Provides
YourViewModel provideViewModel(YourViewModel viewModel){
    return ViewModelProviders.of(mActivity).get(viewModel.getClass());
}
```

> **Usage :**
>
> In your activity like this,
>
> ```
> @Inject
> YourViewModel mViewModel;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     Component mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
>                 .activityModule(new Module(this))
>                 .build();
>     // then
>     mActivityComponent.inject(this);
>
>     // Now you can use your viewModel object in activity anywhere.
> }
> ```

Comment: Let me know if you still have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a lot of time looking for an answer