# How to inject ViewModel using dagger 2.11

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I have **ViewModel** created in activity:

```
mOrdersViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(OrdersViewModel.class);
```

I'd like to inject it as below :

`@Inject OrdersViewModel mOrdersViewModel`

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class OrdersViewModel extends ViewModel {

private OrdersRepository trelloRepository; ();

@Inject
OrdersViewModel(@NonNull OrdersRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

ViewModelFactory module:

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(OrdersViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel bindMovieListViewModel(OrdersViewModel ordersViewModel);

@Binds
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ProjectViewModelFactory projectViewModelFactory);
```

Finally , I get Viewmodel in MainActivity, so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasSupportFragmentInjector, OrderCallback {

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

@Inject
public ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

private OrdersViewModel mOrdersViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mOrdersViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(OrdersViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511909/10271334, let me know if not getting anything or post your code, i'll provide solution about that

Comment: I updated my question,please look at my code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need your view-model Module to a Component class, as a application component? I am not a master dagger, so i am not sure about this.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    ViewModelModule ::class]
)
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: MyApplication): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MyApplication)
}
```